# Re Patent us194726 - I am a direct descendant of William Adolphus Ross - how do I go about claiming ownership of this patent

Tags: ownership, us194726

I am a direct descendant of the person who registered this patent. How would I go about getting this patent assigned to me?

Comment: The tag originally was missing its last digit and pointed to an even older patent for a clock component making method. Is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This patent for an improved bottling machine was issued in 1877 and expired before the beginning of the last century. There are no rights left at all.

Comment: No problem, I got some extra entertainment following the wrong patent number. It was for clock making machinery and the inventor was from my home town, Bristol, Ct.